# Quebrar página com mPDF ao mudar ID

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou tentando fazer uma quebra de página com `mPDF` e `PHP` ao mudar o `ID` do registro, minhas informações estão em uma tabela, mas não sei como fazer, pois minhas tentativas com o `$mpdf->AddPage();` falharam.
Gostaria que sempre que `$RegMaloteExiste->NumeroMalote;` fosse diferente ocorre-se a quebra de página, algo como:

Primeiro criei uma variável que recebe o número do `ID`:

```
$IdNumMalote = $RegMaloteExiste->NumeroMalote;
```

Depois, já no código que gera o PDF fiz isso:

```
if ($IdNumMalote != $RegMaloteExiste) {
    $mpdf->AddPage();
}
```

Até quebra a página, mas com conteúdo não, sei que o `mPDF` tem algumas limitações com tabelas mas não sei se isso é um desses casos.

Uma imagem do relatório que tenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código com `html` e `php`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parte que gera o `PDF`:

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean(); // Finaliza o fluxo

$IdNumMalote = $RegMaloteExiste->NumeroMalote;

include("../../../_comp/externos/MPDF57/mpdf.php");

// cria um novo container PDF no formato A4 com orientação customizada
$mpdf=new mPDF('pt','A4',3,'',8,8,5,14,9,9,'P');

// muda o charset para aceitar caracteres acentuados iso 8859-1 utilizados por mim no banco de dados e na geracao do conteudo PHP com HTML
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='utf-8';

//Algumas configurações do PDF
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// modo de visualização

$cabecalho = "  
                 
                   
                 Relatório Malote/Envelope - {DATE j/m/Y}  
                 Página: {PAGENO}  
                 
             ";
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabecalho);

$rodape = '{DATE j/m/Y H:i}|{PAGENO}/{nb}| Intranet COCARI';
$mpdf->SetFooter($rodape);


// carrega uma folha de estilo - MAGICA!!!
$stylesheet1 = file_get_contents('../../../_comp/externos/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$stylesheet2 = file_get_contents('../../../_css/stgeral.css');

// incorpora a folha de estilo ao PDF
// O parâmetro 1 diz que este é um css/style e deverá ser interpretado como tal
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet1,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet2,1);

// incorpora o corpo ao PDF na posição 2 e deverá ser interpretado como footage. Todo footage é posicao 2 ou 0(padrão).
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);

if ($IdNumMalote != $RegMaloteExiste) {
    $mpdf->AddPage();
}

// define um nome para o arquivo PDF
$arquivo = 'ControleMalote.pdf';

// gera o relatório
$mpdf->Output($arquivo,'I');

exit();
```

Comment: Se tem o código inteiro?

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic, não consigo colocar o código inteiro, tenho html e php juntos.

Comment: Por acaso se deu um AddPage e criou um tabela para cada item?

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic, fiz o AddPage dentro do meu IF e para cada item tem uma tabela.

Comment: Tem que fazer a table completa para cada item e na quebra se manda para outra página... acho que é isso.